# How to add css sheet to the homepage only?

Tags: magento2, css, cms

I'm trying to add a CSS sheet to only the homepage.

I have copied the `cms_index_index.xml` to `app/design/frontend/name/example/Magento_CMS/layout/cms_index_index.xml`

I have added this code:

```
 <body>
    <head>
        <css src="name_example::css/slick-theme.css" />
    </head>
 </body>
```

I have flushed the cache multiple times. I do have the correct theme chosen. How do I add it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typo mistake there. Change

app/design/frontend/name/example/**Magento_CMS**/layout/cms_index_index.xml

To

app/design/frontend/name/example/**Magento_Cms**/layout/cms_index_index.xml

> I do have the correct theme chosen

If you have verified that, then it should work with the path change

**update**

Your xml should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        ... <!-- your css here -->
    </head>
</page>
```

Comment: I did that and I got this error- Element 'head': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( attribute, block, referenceBlock, referenceContainer, container, move, uiComponent ).
Line: 853 So I removed the head tags and got this- Element 'css': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( attribute, block, referenceBlock, referenceContainer, container, move, uiComponent ).
Line: 853

Comment: I have edited my answer, there was another error in your xml file

Comment: You welcome @tjjen

Answer (score 0):

Go to the admin

Content > Pages > Select your home page that you want edit.

In the content area, you can add your CSS inline - also cuts the number of calls down.

```
    <style xml="space"><!--
.product-item .product-reviews-summary .reviews-actions, .catalog-category-view .action.tocart, .action.primary, .action.tocompare, a.action.tocompare, .action.tocompare, .product-item-actions .actions-primary+.actions-secondary { display: none; }.product-item .price-box {margin: 5px;}.product-item-details {text-align: center;}
--></style>
```

I found that I have to use the exact tags for it to work - This is the first line of the content area.

```
<style xml="space"><!--
```

and this end the css.

```
--></style>
```

Below that, add your homepage information as needed.

Hope that helps some.

Comment: The wysiwyg crashes and I get a 500 Internal server error when the <!-- --> comment tags are there upon save. When I remove them and save everything is fine.

Comment: Does it work without the <style xml="space"><!-- ?

Comment: It worked once that was removed.

Comment: @MatthewMcLennan thanks, that may help someone out a lot. It's funny how one thing works some someone, but not another. With so many different setups, servers, and configurations, we need as much help as we can get!